# Operator precedence for custom types and is it possible to have lazy evaluation when multiples of the same operator are present?

Tags: c++, arrays, lazy-evaluation, operator-precedence, associativity

Suppose `array` is a custom type defined as a class that essentially manages a resource

```
class array {
public:
    size_t size;
    float *data;
};
```

To make the `operator -` to perform element-wise scalar addition to `array` and be able to handle both left and right associativity `array+float` and `float+array`, we overload it like so

```
array operator -(float lhs, const array& rhs)
{
    array tmp(rhs.size);
    for (size_t i=0;i<rhs.size;++i)
        tmp.data[i] = lhs-rhs.data[i];

    return tmp;
}

array operator -(array& lhs, float rhs)
{
    array tmp(lhs.size);
    for (size_t i=0;i<lhs.size;++i)
        tmp.data[i] = lhs.data[i]-rhs;
    return tmp;
}
```

Assume that we also have a `initializer_list` constructor so we can do

```
array marray = {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f};
```

Now for

```
std::cout << marray-5.0 << "\n"; 
std::cout << 2.0-marray << "\n";
```

We get the desired result, however doing

```
std::cout << 2.0-marray-5.0 << "\n";
```

Does not even call the second overload for `marray-5.0`, and gives me nonsensical values for the last two elements of the output array, of-course `2.0-(marray-5.0)` does solve the problem, but is not a generic solution. So the question is:

1. What is really happening under the hood and why the second overload is not called at all? Does this have to do with operator-precedence?
2. My second question is regarding the second case i.e. `2.0-(marray-5.0)` here we call once the operator for the `float+array` and once for `array+float`. So the array is traversed twice. Is it possible to have lazy-evaluation to perform global operation at once when multiples of the same operator and/or multiples of multiple operators are present?

**Edit:** [Here](https://ideone.com/HQ4xhS) is a minimal working example. Note the `missing const` in the second overload, which I have used to remove the ambiguity with another `array operator -(const array& other)` overload for element-wise subtraction of two arrays. I guess this is the cause of the first problem.

Comment: You need to provide a SMALL but complete sample of code that exhibits your problem.   You have not, as exhibited by code that attempts to stream an `array` (no streaming operator), no evidence of a constructor to do sizing, etc.   Any one of those missing things could be a contributor, which puts anyone trying to help you in a position of trying to guess what is missing.   Yes it is possible to do lazy evaluation, but that relies on several functions (members, constructors, etc) working in tandem.

Comment: I have added the link to a small working example that produces the result.

Comment: BTW switch to either `std::vector<float>` or `std::unique_ptr<float[]>` ASAP.  There's no reason to be writing destructors by hand, and the latter option has zero overhead.

Comment: And what you are looking for to achieve lazy evaluation is the "Expression Templates" pattern.  It's quite popular among C++ matrix libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your "array - float" operator doesn't take the array as a const reference.  As a result, the temporary created for `2.0 - marray` can't bind to it.  In your linked-to minimal working example, you use `2 - marray - 5`, and when the compiler generates code to subtract 5 it will construct a new array using the constructor that takes an integer, then call the subtraction operator between two array members.

Change your second subtraction operator to `array operator -(const array& lhs, float rhs)`.

Comment: And it would also be a good idea to use `explicit` on that one-parameter constructor so that this kind of unintended conversion can't happen.